# Taking the top 64 bits from a multiplication in verilog

Tags: verilog, quartus

I have two 64 bit registers that I'd like to multiply together. I'm only interested in the top 64 bits of the result. What is the best way to write this in verilog? I tried

```
c = (a*b)[127:64]
```

which doesn't work. So right now I'm assigning the result of the multiplication to a 128 bit register, then only ever use the top 64 bits of that register. But it seems like a waste to have the lower 64 bits calculated and stored. Or is the synthesizer smart enough to never actually synthesize these bits if they are never used?

Comment: the result of this multiplication **is** 128 bits, so you need to provide a register to keep them. I believe that synthesizer, if it is capable of synthesizing multiplication at all, would need all of them. Otherwise you would need to implement your own custom multiplier which would not produce the lower half at all.

Comment: The synthesizer is able so synthesize the 64x64->128 multiplication (I've tried it out). And yes, I've also implemented it with my own multiplication routine (which internally uses only 32x32->64 bit multiplications). I'd like to know if there is a (better) way to write this in a standard/efficient way in verilog.

Answer (score 3):

```
wire c_tmp[127:0];
reg c[64:0];

assign c_tmp = a*b;
assign c = c_tmp[127:64];
```

The multiplication result will always be 128-bits. You can't save that cost. All you can save is the register cost. While making `c_tmp` as wire you are just using the wires not actual registers. And, you can choose to make `c` as 64-bit register.

Answer (score 2):

If you can move to SystemVerilog, you can write

```
c = {a*b}[127:64];
```

SystemVerilog allows you to part-select a concatenation. But as others have mentioned, it won't save you that much hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
typedef logic [127:0] QWORD;

c = (QWORD'(a*b)) >> 64;
```